# Working on Search Criteria and limit the number of filters displayed on Search Criteria section

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-controller

I am working on a Search Function using custom controller. I have 4 Filters (Account Name, Country, Account Type, Contact Name) in my Search Criteria Section.

I have a requirements that, it must have a facility where System Administrator can limit the number of filters displayed on the Search Criteria.

How will I do this?

I think there will be a scenario that the admin can choose either, which the four filter is to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this

- Have a custom setting to maintain which fields needs to be enabled as the filter criteria for your search.
- In visual force page, display only those filters which are enabled in custom setting by system administrator.
- In controller, write a dynamic SOQL to get the results based on the filter criteria.

Comment: I checked the custom setting and i have no idea on how to create a field or to enabled. Can you share me a link? So that i can refer on it.

Comment: Or Can you give me a sample? on how to create? Sorry i am just a newbie on this work.